# Object set on a visualforce page to repeat up to 5 times. Why doesn't my object appear?

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-object

I can't seem to call the objects out on the database and onto a visualforce page using this set up:

```
public with sharing class HarborEventController {

private final Event__c event;
public HarborEventController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    this.eventlist = (Event__c)controller.getRecord();
}


public Integer eventcount{get;set;}
public HarborEventController (){
   eventcount = [SELECT COUNT() FROM Event__c];    
}


public list<Event__c> mainlist {get;set;}  
public list<Event__c> displayevents(){
    mainlist = new list<Event__c>();
    String mainsoql = 'SELECT Id, Name__C, Message__c, Display_Date__c, FROM Event__c'; 
    mainsoql += 'ORDER BY Display_date__c LIMIT :5';
    mainlist = Database.query(mainsoql);
    return mainlist;
}
```

and the visualforce page :

```
    <apex:composition template="eh_base">
          <apex:define name="heros-content">  
          </apex:define>
      <apex:define name="content">
       <section id="services-sec">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="row" style="padding-top: 60px;">


    <apex:outputPanel layout="block" rendered="{!AND(NOT(ISNULL(mainlist)),mainlist.size>0)}">
        <apex:form id="blockofeventtorepeat">
            <apex:repeat value="{!mainlist}" var="evententry" id="repeat">
                <div class="col-md-9">
                   <h3><apex:outputLink styleClass="evententry-header block" value="{!$Page.eh_eventdetails}?id={!evententry.id}">{!evententry.Name__c}</apex:outputLink></h3>
                    <apex:outputPanel >
                     <p>
                         <img src="{!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download, evententry.Attachments[0].Id)}" class="pull-left img-responsive" alt="" style="max-width:180px;max-height:100px"/>    
                    {!evententry.Message__c}
                     </p>
                       <apex:outputLink styleclass="btn btn-sm btn-default" value="{!$Page.eh_eventdetails}?id={!evententry.id}">Read More</apex:outputLink>

                    </apex:outputPanel>
                </div>
                </apex:repeat>
                </apex:form>
                </apex:outputPanel> 

                </div>
            </div>




            </section>      
    </apex:define>
</apex:composition>
```

Can anyone suggest how I can able to get the event data from the query and display it on a visualforce page in a repeat tag? I've tried everything and it doesn't work. 
I've already tried passing the query from an anonymous user and the results were as expected

Comment: have you tried debugging your mainsoql variable, maybe from the dev console using execute apex as anonymous, to validate that the result you are expecting is returned ?

Comment: I've already tried that it displays the infromation fine.

Comment: can you include that in your question, just so the rest are aware (it would be appreciated) thanks!

Comment: Where are you calling displayEvents? That's the method that populates the property used in the repeat

Comment: your visualforce page code seems incomplete. please provide a complete "reproduceable example". thanks

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts as it removes any context your question and the answers have. If you do not want your code to be public don't post it on the internet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not calling displayEvents(), which is a good thing, because your code would be crashing. Your SOQL is incorrect. You've basically written it as:

```
SELECT Id, Name__C, Message__c, Display_Date__c, 
FROM Event__cORDER BY Display_date__c 
LIMIT :5
```

The final field must not be followed by a comma, you forgot a space between Event__c and ORDER, and :5 is not a valid dynamic bind expression (you must bind to a variable).

You would have found most of these errors if you'd use an actual inline query. Call your displayEvents() method inside your constructor, and you should be good to go (after fixing your query).

Consider using inline SOQL unless you *need* a dynamic query; it saves a lot of headaches:

```
mainList = [SELECT Name__c, Message__c, Display_Date__c
            FROM Event__c
            ORDER BY Display_Date__c
            LIMIT 5];
```

Comment: Thank you for feedback, Where in the constructor should I place the method?

Comment: @Greg Anywhere you like.